# Extracting data digitally

Tags: image-processing

[image]

I have 200 copies of this page(15 * 10 matrix) and i have to write all the numbers from 0 - 9 in each corresponding cell and then extract those digits digitally in a seperate image of (32*32 pixels) for each digit, after scanning each page once. How can i achieve this? This is required for my research purpose. I am a CS student so i can code too.

Update:
For mark : Here is one of the scanned image

[image]

This is for some local language ( 0 - 9) ..

Update 2:

The commands for the previous image are working fine but on new images,something is getting wrong(some kind of offsets)..
I am attaching the image below
[image]

What changes do u suggest ?

Comment: How about giving us a scanned page so we can see the quality, alignment, resolution, contrast that you have available?

Comment: Simple way: Install ImageJ, read this http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/How-to-create-a-regular-grid-of-rectangular-ROI-s-td3685056.html, implement.
If you want to create your own application consider getting into OpenCV or any other image processing library. This is a very basic task any library should be able to solve.

Comment: @mark Setchell - See my updated post

Comment: @Piglet Can you ellaborate a bit please

Comment: scan every page well aligned. then you can use a regular grid of squares to crop the numbers and resize them to 32x32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I have taken your feedback and improved the algorithm to the following `bash` script now...

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# dice
#
# Trim borders off an image (twice) and then dice into 10x15 cells.
# 
# Usage: ./dice image
################################################################################
# Pick up image name from first parameter
image="$1"
echo DEBUG: Processing image $image...

# Apply median filter to remove noisy black dots around image and then get the
# dimensions of the "trim box" - note we don't use the (degraded) median-filtered image in
# later steps.
trimbox=$(convert "$image" -median 9x9 -fuzz 50% -format %@ info:)
echo DEBUG: trimbox $trimbox

# Now trim original unfiltered image into stage1-$$.png (for debug)
convert "$1" -crop $trimbox +repage stage1-$$.png
echo DEBUG: Trimmed outer: stage1-$$.png

# Now trim column headings
convert stage1-$$.png -crop 2000x2590+120+190 +repage stage2-$$.png
echo DEBUG: Trimmed inner: stage2-$$.png

# Now slice into 10x15 rectangles
echo DEBUG: Slicing and dicing
convert stage2-$$.png -crop 10x15@ +repage rectangles-%03d.png

# Now trim the edges off the rectangles and resize all to a constant size
for f in rectangles*png; do
   echo DEBUG: Trimming and resizing $f
   trimbox=$(convert "$f" -median 9x9 -shave 15x15 -bordercolor black -border 15 -threshold 50% -floodfill +0+0 white -fuzz 50% -format %@ info:)
   echo DEBUG: Cell trimbox $trimbox
   convert "$f" -crop $trimbox +repage -resize 32x32! "$f"
done
```

Here are the resulting cells - i.e. 150 separate image files. I have put a red border around the individual cells/files so you can see their extent:

[image]

**Original Answer**

I would do that with **ImageMagick** which is free and installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows too. There are Perl, PHP, Java, node, .NET, Ruby, C/C++ bindings too if you prefer those languages. Here I am using the command line in Terminal.

First job is to get rid of noise and trim the outer edges:

```
convert scan.jpg -median 3x3 -fuzz 50% -trim +repage trimmed1.png
```

[image]

Now, trim again to get rid of outer frame and column titles across the top:

```
convert trimmed1.png -crop 2000x2590+120+190 +repage trimmed2.png
```

[image]

Now divide into 10 cells by 15 cells and save as `rectangles-nnn.png`

```
convert trimmed2.png -crop 10x15@ rectangles-%03d.png
```

Check what we got - yes, 150 images:

```
ls -l rect*

rectangles-000.png  rectangles-022.png  rectangles-044.png  rectangles-066.png  rectangles-088.png  rectangles-110.png  rectangles-132.png
rectangles-001.png  rectangles-023.png  rectangles-045.png  rectangles-067.png  rectangles-089.png  rectangles-111.png  rectangles-133.png
rectangles-002.png  rectangles-024.png  rectangles-046.png  rectangles-068.png  rectangles-090.png  rectangles-112.png  rectangles-134.png
rectangles-003.png  rectangles-025.png  rectangles-047.png  rectangles-069.png  rectangles-091.png  rectangles-113.png  rectangles-135.png
rectangles-004.png  rectangles-026.png  rectangles-048.png  rectangles-070.png  rectangles-092.png  rectangles-114.png  rectangles-136.png
rectangles-005.png  rectangles-027.png  rectangles-049.png  rectangles-071.png  rectangles-093.png  rectangles-115.png  rectangles-137.png
rectangles-006.png  rectangles-028.png  rectangles-050.png  rectangles-072.png  rectangles-094.png  rectangles-116.png  rectangles-138.png
rectangles-007.png  rectangles-029.png  rectangles-051.png  rectangles-073.png  rectangles-095.png  rectangles-117.png  rectangles-139.png
rectangles-008.png  rectangles-030.png  rectangles-052.png  rectangles-074.png  rectangles-096.png  rectangles-118.png  rectangles-140.png
rectangles-009.png  rectangles-031.png  rectangles-053.png  rectangles-075.png  rectangles-097.png  rectangles-119.png  rectangles-141.png
rectangles-010.png  rectangles-032.png  rectangles-054.png  rectangles-076.png  rectangles-098.png  rectangles-120.png  rectangles-142.png
rectangles-011.png  rectangles-033.png  rectangles-055.png  rectangles-077.png  rectangles-099.png  rectangles-121.png  rectangles-143.png
rectangles-012.png  rectangles-034.png  rectangles-056.png  rectangles-078.png  rectangles-100.png  rectangles-122.png  rectangles-144.png
rectangles-013.png  rectangles-035.png  rectangles-057.png  rectangles-079.png  rectangles-101.png  rectangles-123.png  rectangles-145.png
rectangles-014.png  rectangles-036.png  rectangles-058.png  rectangles-080.png  rectangles-102.png  rectangles-124.png  rectangles-146.png
rectangles-015.png  rectangles-037.png  rectangles-059.png  rectangles-081.png  rectangles-103.png  rectangles-125.png  rectangles-147.png
rectangles-016.png  rectangles-038.png  rectangles-060.png  rectangles-082.png  rectangles-104.png  rectangles-126.png  rectangles-148.png
rectangles-017.png  rectangles-039.png  rectangles-061.png  rectangles-083.png  rectangles-105.png  rectangles-127.png  rectangles-149.png
rectangles-018.png  rectangles-040.png  rectangles-062.png  rectangles-084.png  rectangles-106.png  rectangles-128.png
rectangles-019.png  rectangles-041.png  rectangles-063.png  rectangles-085.png  rectangles-107.png  rectangles-129.png
rectangles-020.png  rectangles-042.png  rectangles-064.png  rectangles-086.png  rectangles-108.png  rectangles-130.png
rectangles-021.png  rectangles-043.png  rectangles-065.png  rectangles-087.png  rectangles-109.png  rectangles-131.png
```

Look at first couple:

[image]
[image]

You can do those 3 steps in 1 like this:

```
convert scan.jpg -median 3x3 -fuzz 50% -trim +repage  \
   -crop 2000x2590+120+190 +repage                    \
   -crop 10x15@ rectangles-%03d.png
```

You may want to shave a few pixels off each side of each image and resize to 32x32 with something like (untested):

```
mogrify -shave 3x3 -resize 32x32! rectangles*png
```

Comment: Wow!!! Thanks for the help! I am going to try this and will inform you in case of any errors/problems...Thanks a  lot :)

Comment: Hi Mark! I tried it,it works quite good.The only trouble i am having now is that some lines are coming too with some images...So is there any way so that after the 2nd step,we can erase the matrix(15*10)  without affecting the contents inside each cell so that finally each image is free of any types of lines ?

Comment: Try running `mogrify -shave 5x5 -resize 32x32! +repage rectangles*png` at the end to trim all the edges and make them into 32x32 pixel squares.

Comment: See my updated post..The commands works fine for the 1st image but something is getting wrong for the 2nd image..do we need to change some kind of offsets ?

Comment: It is not the offsets - it is noise. There are black dots around the edge of the outer frame which are preventing the trimming of the edges because it is trimming white pixels. I'll need to make a couple of little changes - are you ok with a short bash shell script if I write it? For the moment, try changing the `-median 3x3` to `-median 9x9` and see if that helps. It will blur the image, but I can fix that in a shell script.

Comment: Ya, i know bash programming.. I am comfortable with it..:)

Comment: Ya it worked, but i want to know the concept..so that i can change the code myself..(Every CS student should know why things work ;) ).. What changed when i changed 9 * 9  from 3 * 3 ?

Comment: And one more thing, The 150 images that i got..I need to just keep their bounding box in (32*32).. Not the whole thing so that each digit can have approximately the same position.. Is there any way to do the same.

Comment: I have built that in - by drawing a black border inside the image edges and then flood filling from the edges with white so that anything black touching an edge (like the lines of your grid) get overwritten with white. Then I can trim all the white backgrounds off before resizing.